# Can't execute 32bit on 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 and newer

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Up through Ubuntu 11 I have been able to successfully execute 32bit files on 64bit os with the 32bit libraries in place. With Ubuntu 14.04 however I get seg fault errors. Originally I thought it could be vm.mmap_min_addr which for the newer kernels defaults to 4096. But resetting it had no effect.

All the files execute properly  as root.

What am I missing?